# Can you give me a hint on this proof of a subspace of vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces

$V=\{(x_n)\in l^2 | $It has only a finite number of vectors$ \neq 0\}$
prove V is a subspace of $l^2$ but it isn't closed.

I have problems understanding what does $l ^2$ means, and what the sentence on the set emans...

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be some countable set, so $X\cong \mathbb{N}$. Then $l^2(\mathbb{N})=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mid x_n\in \mathbb{C}, \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|^2<\infty\right\}$ is the space of square summable sequences. Your set is the subset of finite sequences (the tail is zero). Obviously, your subset is a subspace. When you say it's not closed, it means that you have a topology on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. The standard topology is the topology coming from the norm $\left||(x_n)_n\right\|_2:=\sqrt{\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|^2}$. Now use the other answer to show that this subspace is not closed.

Comment: Just to understand, those secuences ( in R) could be 5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 for example?

Comment: Yes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

$l^2 = \{(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}: x_n \in \Bbb{R}, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 < \infty \}$ and $V=\{(x_n)\in l^2 : x_n = 0 \text{ for all but finite } n\}$. Try to write $\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ as a limit of elements from $V$.